# API for Earnings date

Tags: equities, earnings, event-study

Is there any API for getting past/future earnings date for a specific symbol?

I tried TDAmeritrade API, Ally and IEX, none of them provide this information yet.

Answer (score 3):

I just found this free simple API, returning today's earnings by default and symbols with earnings call if you pass date:

```
https://api.earningscalendar.net/
```

or

```
https://api.earningscalendar.net/?date=20190925
```

Comment: Just to make sure. Is this API free? Is there any limitation on using it? It seems that the second linked does work. Could you update it with a current link?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short python3 script that will parse the info that you're looking for from Yahoo Finance:

```
import requests
import json
import pprint

symbol='T'
url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol
resp=requests.get(url)
r=resp.text

i1=0
i1=r.find('root.App.main', i1)
i1=r.find('{', i1)
i2=r.find("\n", i1)
i2=r.rfind(';', i1, i2)
jsonstr=r[i1:i2]      

data = json.loads(jsonstr)
pprint.pprint(data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['calendarEvents']['earnings'])
```